# Pull data from website table that has a tag name "table" and nothing else

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

The data to import is in a table that has a tag name "table" and nothing else.

When I assign all tables in the page, I think it is not counted as a table.

```
Sub PullData()

    Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim hdoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim HEL As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim ha, hb, hc, hd, he, hf, hg, hh, hi, hj As String
    Dim i, x As Integer
    i = 2

    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuote.jsp?symbol=FEL"
    Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Loop

    Set hdoc = IE.document
    Set HEL = hdoc.getElementById("tab8")
    HEL.Click
    Set HEL = hdoc.getElementById("period")
    HEL.Value = "3months"
    Set HEL = hdoc.getElementById("get")
    HEL.Click

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you show the HTML of the page so we have a better idea of what the DOM looks like?

Comment: What is the visible text of that table name? It's really unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a querystring in the URL to return that info. This means you can go straight to a much quicker [XMLHTTP](https://codingislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba/) method which is much faster than opening a browser and making selections.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetTable()
    Dim sResponse As String, html As HTMLDocument, clipboard As Object, ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/getHistoricalData.jsp?symbol=FEL&series=EQ&fromDate=undefined&toDate=undefined&datePeriod=3months", False
        .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
        .send
        sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    html.body.innerHTML = sResponse

    clipboard.SetText html.querySelector("table").outerHTML
    clipboard.PutInClipboard
    ws.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial
End Sub
```

---

Less tidy is intercepting the URL used for file download and using that for binary download:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub DownloadFile()
    Dim http As Object
    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    http.Open "GET", "https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/getHistoricalData.jsp?symbol=FEL&series=EQ&fromDate=undefined&toDate=undefined&datePeriod=3months&hiddDwnld=true", False
    http.send
    With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        .Open
        .Type = 1
        .write http.responseBody
        .SaveToFile "C:\Users\User\Desktop\TestDownload.csv" '<== specify your path here
        .Close
    End With
    Debug.Print "FileDownloaded"
    Exit Sub
errhand:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description
        MsgBox "Download failed"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: One more problem i have, i want to draw data row of specific date like 03-sep.

Comment: You said you wanted the table. Has this not answered the original question? And is your new question hoe to get data for a specific date?

Comment: yes the code is working. i have many links from where i have to bring data of 3rd sep.

Comment: So, that is a new question?

Comment: The query string looks like it has parameters where you can specify dates.

Comment: Almost, let me first explain it clearly. I need the any middle row of table. Yes it is another question but it is continue question of last one